# Transitive dependencies error while installing cocoa pods

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods, google-signin

I want to integrate "Login with google" in my application. I tried to use pods, but i am getting error which is as follows:

The `'Pods-ProjectName`' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: `ProjectPath/GoogleAppUtilities/Libraries/libOpenInChrome.a`

My Pod file code is as follows:

```
target 'ProjectName' do

use_frameworks!

pod "OAuthSwift", "~> 0.3.4"
pod "Haneke", "~> 1.0"
pod "Alamofire", "~> 1.2"
pod "IJReachability", :git => "https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/IJReachability.git"
pod "iCarousel"
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
pod 'Google/SignIn'

end
```

I am using Crashlytics also. Without `Google/signIn` i am able to create pods workspace successfully.

Any solution on this.

Comment: Please provide your Podfile code

Comment: I have tried adding between `target 'TestProject' do` and `end`  the line `pod 'GoogleSignIn'` , then using `pod install` from terminal added the dependencies correctly.

Comment: @aramusss I edited my question and added my pod file code.

Comment: Try using `pod 'GoogleSignIn'`, and then pod install and pod update

Comment: @aramusss I tried this. Still getting same error.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding [cocoapods documentation for version 0.36](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/), you can not add static libraries to your project. Google pod seems to have dependencies to some static libraries making `pod install` crash.

If you use ObjectiveC, and you remove the `use_frameworks!` part, you will have no problem.

Another option, of course, is to add the Google lib directly to the project so you won't be using cocoapods.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines of code to your pod file to ignore transitive dependencies:

```
pre_install do |installer|
    def installer.verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies 
    end
end
```

If you're using podfile like **MIHCrypto** uses static libraries added all dependency libraries to project and change mach-O-Type to static as per below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to your podfile and insert the following

```
pre_install do |installer|
def installer.verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies; end
end
```

This worked for me.